# Python: Modify tuple in list

Tags: python, list, tuples

My actual output looks like this:

```
target = [([('Kid', '200-5'), (u'Rock', '200-6')], u's725')]
```

How can I modify data in the tuple such that I can return, at the end, the modified list which has the same format as target?

For example: I'd like to change 'kid' in 'adult', such that the rest stays, i.e. I receive: newTarget = [([('adult', '200-5'), (u'Rock', '200-6')], u's725')]

My idea: Copy all the data of target in a temporary list, modify things and create the same format as in target.

BUT: How can I achieve this concretely? 
Until now, I could Change and modify things, but I didn't get the same format again...

Comment: what do you mean by "same format"? btw, `[()]` is the same as `[]`

Comment: I'm confused. What is it that you're starting with here? What is it you're trying to modify?

Comment: "[()] is the same as []" - this is true. In general, the comma is what makes a tuple, not the parens.

Comment: "How can I modify data in the tuple..." remember that tuples are [immutables](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: Ok with the parenthesis. I'd like to modify the names, i.e. for example: 'Kid' should be changed in 'Adult'. But the rest should stay...

Comment: `[()]` is most certainly different from `[]`. The first is a list with one item, the empty tuple. The second is the empty list. The comma is only necessary with one more items; `(,)` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
l = list(target[0][0][0])
l[0] = 'Adult'
target[0][0][0] = tuple(l)
```

Comment: How would this look like with a variable number of tuples?

Answer (score 1):

Since tuples are immutable, you cannot modify their elements—you must replace them with new tuples.  Lists are mutable, so you can replace individual parts as needed:

```
>>> x = [(1, 2), (3, 4), 5]
>>> x[0] = (x[0][0], 0)
>>> x
[(1, 0), (3, 4), 5]
```

In the above example, I create a list `x` containing tuples as its first and second elements and an int as its third.  On the second line, I construct a new tuple to swap in to the first position of x, containing the first element of the old tuple, and a new element `0` to replace the `2`.

Comment: I understand your example - I did the same. But how would you handle the problem that you don't know the number of tuples? For example if we have now this: target = [([('Name', '200-5'), (u'Irgendwas', '200-6')], u's725'), ([('Nochwas', '250-5'), (u'undsoweiter', '250-6')], u's985')]

Comment: If you have a variable number of tuples to replace, you'll have to loop over the list somehow, either by index for in-place modification or building a new list, constructing new tuples to swap in as you go.  But the answer to exactly what you must do is very dependent on the structure you expect to be modifying and its meaning; it's not possible to generally answer the question more than I have.

Answer (score 0):

You will need recursion if you need to be more flexible

```
target = [([('Kid', '200-5'), (u'Rock', '200-6')], u's725')]

def search_and_replace(inlist):
        res = []
        for t in inlist:
            if isinstance(t, list):
                res.append(search_and_replace(t))
            elif isinstance(t, tuple):
                t1, t2 = t 
                if t1 == 'Kid':
                    t1 = 'adult'
                elif isinstance(t1, list):
                    t1 = search_and_replace(t1)
                res.append((t1, t2)) 
            else:
                res.append(t)

        return  res 


print search_and_replace(target)
```

Comment: Cool! Glad you find it useful. Please remember to accept my answer!